# como puedo hacer que un numero que se cambia cada 5 segundos se muestre en la pagina

Tags: javascript

El problema es que el numero que cambia cada 5 segundos, se tarda 5 segundos en encontrar un valor, y la pagina lo marca como indefinido.

Una vez que encuentra un valor tendria que cargar la pagina otra vez y empezaria a querer volver a hallar un valor despues de 5 segundos.

¿Saben como puede hallar un valor enseguida, y que ademas lo cambie cada 5 segundos?

```html
<script>
var genesis= new Array("En el principio creó Dios los cielos y la tierra." , "Genesis 1:2 Y la tierra estaba desordenada y vacía, y las tinieblas estaban sobre la faz del abismo, y el Espíritu de Dios se movía sobre la faz de las aguas.",  "Genesis 1:3 Y dijo Dios: Sea la luz; y fue la luz.",
//enrealidad el arreglo es mas que esto pero es para una idea basica 
var numerito
function generateRandom() {
let num = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
numerito =(num);
console.log(num);


}

setInterval(generate, 5000);
//generate();

document.write (genesis [numerito]);
</script>
```

Comment: A donde se consulta el numero? dependiendo del origen podrias controlarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *El problema es que el numero que cambia cada 5 segundos, se tarda 5 segundos en encontrar un valor,y la pagina lo marca como indefinido.*

Es posible que esten obteniendo un numero que no esta dentro de lo indices del array

> Una vez que encuentra un valor tendria que cargar la pagina otra vez y empezaria a querer volver a hallar un valor despues de 5 segundos.

Con javascript no se requiere normalmente volver a cargar la pagina, ya que puede solitiar informacion que cambia sin recargar todo

> ¿Saben como puede hallar un valor enseguida, y que ademas lo cambie cada 5 segundos?

Con el setInterval que usas esta bien el planteamiento, es quien se encargaria de mostrar un el texto en la pagina cada 5 segundos

El numero que necesitas si es random, en tu codigo esta bien excepto por usar un numero constante como 1000, es mejor usar `genesis.length` para mantener el numero dentro de los posibles valores del array

Si por el contrario el numero viene de otra pagina u otro recurso puede usar la funcion **fetch** que te permite carga recursos con javascript y ya tu escoges que hacer con ellos, sea cargar la imagen poner el texto en algun parte de la pagina, etc

Te dejo un par de ejemplos, siente libre de preguntar en los comentarios de la respuesta, y de editar tu pregunta si ves que te falto un detalle por aclarar

```js
var genesis = new Array("En el principio creó Dios los cielos y la tierra." , "Genesis 1:2 Y la tierra estaba desordenada y vacía, y las tinieblas estaban sobre la faz del abismo, y el Espíritu de Dios se movía sobre la faz de las aguas.",  "Genesis 1:3 Y dijo Dios: Sea la luz; y fue la luz.")

function generateRandom() {
  /* usamos el tamaño del array (genesis.length) para que nunca devuelva un indice que no tenga un valor, y que al acceder al array no devuelva 'undefined' */
  let num = Math.floor(Math.random()*genesis.length);
  return num;
}

function showRandom(){
  let num = generateRandom();
  document.write('<br />'+genesis[num]);
}
setInterval(showRandom, 5000);
```

Si estás intentando cargar todo el array de datos cada vez que buscas un texto aleatorio tiene sentido que se demoré dependiendo de que tanta informacion entregue

Un ejemplo, si estuvieses cargando la informacion desde una url como https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts que te entrega toda la informacion pero es poca asi que no toma tanto tiempo:

```js
function getRandom(){
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    fetch(url, { mode: 'cors', cache: 'no-cache', headers: { Accept: 'application/json'}})
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data)=> {
      let num = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length);
      showRandom(data[num]);    
      
    }).catch((err)=> {         
        console.error(err) 
  })
}
function showRandom(texto){
  document.write('<br/>'+texto.body);
}
setInterval(getRandom, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var genesis= new Array("En el principio creó Dios los cielos y la tierra." , "Genesis 1:2 Y la tierra estaba desordenada y vacía, y las tinieblas estaban sobre la faz del abismo, y el Espíritu de Dios se movía sobre la faz de las aguas.",  "Genesis 1:3 Y dijo Dios: Sea la luz; y fue la luz.")
generateRandom();

function generateRandom() {
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
//console.log(num);
setTimeout(generateRandom, 1000);
document.getElementById("pantalla").innerHTML = genesis[num];
}
```

```html
<p id="pantalla"></p>
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer], editar y agregar una explicación ayudaría a mejorar la calidad de tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Bien, según tengo entendido, la tarea es muy simple, desea encontrar un índice aleatorio que exista dentro de la palabra. Por lo tanto, primero debe encontrar la longitud de su cadena. De esta manera, sabrá cuáles son sus limitaciones para el índice. Ahora está en el camino correcto utilizando la función SetInterval.

**El problema con su solución actual es que está intentando acceder a un índice que no existe** y es por eso que obtiene el valor de indefinido. A continuación, debemos comprender cómo se comparten las variables y el alcance en el entorno.

Veo aquí que está utilizando dos variables distintas para capturar el mismo valor. Esto se puede resolver usando el alcance. También noto que está creando la matriz con la función de constructor. Esto está bien, pero no es necesario ya que [una cadena en JavaScript tiene índices a los que puede acceder de forma predeterminada](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String).

**El siguiente problema que veo es que ciertamente está creando un número aleatorio cada 5 segundos, pero solo está actualizando el documento una vez.** Esto se debe al hecho de que la función que escribe en el documento no se llama dentro de la función de intervalo. También debes intentar almacenar el elemento en el que va a escribir dentro de una variable. Estoy usando la función **textContent** para escribir al elemento por seguridad. date una leida a este [documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) igual .

**Solución**

```
function generarNumeroAlatorio(){
  let elemento = document.querySelector('body') // cambia dependiendo tu selector.
  let genesis = "En el principio creó Dios los cielos y la tierra." , "Genesis 1:2 Y la tierra estaba desordenada y vacía, y las tinieblas estaban sobre la faz del abismo, y el Espíritu de Dios se movía sobre la faz de las aguas.",  "Genesis 1:3 Y dijo Dios: Sea la luz; y fue la luz.";
  let numerito = ()=>{ return Math.floor(Math.random() * (genesis.length - 1) ); };
  setInterval(()=>{ elemento.textContent(genesis[numerito()]) },5000);

}
```

Ahora, si revisamos el código, está haciendo lo siguiente:

- Almacene el elemento en el que deseamos escribir.
- Almacene la expresión de cadena en una variable.
- Cree una función anónima que devuelva un índice existente. La
  expresión primitiva calculada multiplicando un número aleatorio por
  la longitud de nuestra cadena. Luego usamos la función "piso" para
  obtener un número real. Esto se debe al hecho de que ["Math.random"
  devuelve un número flotante.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random)
- Finalmente, nuestra función de intervalo establecido se llama cada 5
  segundos. dentro de esta función vemos que el elemento está llamando
  a su método "textContent". Como parámetro, estamos pasando el valor
  recuperado de nuestra cadena usando la función numerito.